# Importing other .js files in Buster.js tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, buster.js

I'm making my first attempt at Javascript testing, with Buster.js

I've followed the instructions at [the Buster site](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/getting-started/#write-tests) to run "states the obvious" test. However, I haven't been able to import any of my existing .js files into the tests.

For instance, I have a file `js/testLibrary.js`, containing:

```
function addTwo(inp) {
  return inp+2;
}
```

and a file `test/first-test.js`, containing:

```
// Node.js tests
var buster = require("buster");
var testLibrary = require("../js/testLibrary.js");
var assert = buster.referee.assert;

buster.testCase("A module", {
    "Test The Library": function() {
            result = addTwo(3);
            console.log(result);
            assert(true, 'a message for you');
    }
});
```

Running `buster-test` gives:

```
Error: A module Test The Library
    ReferenceError: addTwo is not defined
    [...]
```

Replacing `result = addTwo(3);` with `result = testLibrary.addTwo(3);` gives:

```
Error: A module Test The Library
    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addTwo'
    [...]
```

I'm probably missing something really basic, but at present, I'm completely stumped. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are not exporting this function from the module.
Take a look at that:
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Comment: Perfect, that did it! I guess it probably shows that I've never used Node.js before, either :) thank you!